# When should I open and close a website's cached WCF proxy?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, performance, caching, channelfactory

I've browsed around the other articles on StackOverflow that relate to caching WCF proxies for reuse, and I've read [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/wenlong/archive/2007/10/26/best-practice-always-open-wcf-client-proxy-explicitly-when-it-is-shared.aspx) article explaining why I should explicitly open the proxy before calling anything on it.  I'm still a little hazy on the best implementation details.

My question is: when should I open and close proxies for service calls on a website, and what should their lifetime be (per call, per request, or per web app)?  We aren't planning on leveraging cached security contexts at the moment (but it's not unforeseeable).

Thanks!